# Windows 10 Bazel_SH configuration

Tags: windows-10, python-3.5, bazel

I am trying to run a bazel build command following the guide presented on [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/tutorials/image_retraining), and I have been unsuccessful thus far. I am using Python version 3.5.0

Bazel has been installed and configured correctly using the guide on the [website](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/windows.html) but to no avail.  I am always receiving the same error:

```
ERROR: in target '//external:cc_toolchain': no such package '@local_config_cc//': Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_username/ykvutwrt/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl", line 32
            configure_windows_toolchain(repository_ctx)
    File "C:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_username/ykvutwrt/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/windows_cc_configure.bzl", line 365, in configure_windows_toolchain
            tpl(repository_ctx, "CROSSTOOL", {"%{cpu...}": ""})
    File "C:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_username/ykvutwrt/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/windows_cc_configure.bzl", line 377, in tpl
            _get_escaped_windows_msys_crosstool_content(repository_ctx)
    File "C:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_username/ykvutwrt/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/windows_cc_configure.bzl", line 34, in _get_escaped_windows_msys_crosstool_content
            get_env_var(repository_ctx, "BAZEL_SH")
    File "C:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_username/ykvutwrt/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/lib_cc_configure.bzl", line 48, in get_env_var
            auto_configure_fail(("'%s' environment variable is n...))
    File "C:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/_bazel_username/ykvutwrt/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/lib_cc_configure.bzl", line 30, in auto_configure_fail
            fail(("\n%sAuto-Configuration Error:%...)))

Auto-Configuration Error: 'BAZEL_SH' environment variable is not set
```

I am not really sure what to do any more.

Answer (score 3):

The `BAZEL_SH` env var isn't set, did you run the following command shown under the requirements section?

> You also need to set the BAZEL_SH environment variable to point to
>   bash.exe. For example in the Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe):
>
> `set BAZEL_SH=C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe`

You may want to use `setx` to [set the environment variable permanently](https://superuser.com/questions/916649/what-is-the-difference-between-setx-and-set-in-environment-variables-in-windows) to live across shells.

Comment: Hmm, setting `Bazel_SH` should work, which version of Bazel are you running?

Comment: I am using Bazel version 0.5.4.  I also attempted to run the setx command, but I am not structuring the command correctly.